# Does closing InputStream close the Channel associated with it?

Tags: java, nio

If I create a `Channel` from an `InputStream`, and then close the `InputStream`, will it close the associated `Channel`? Do I need to close the associated `Channel` explicitly? I know closing Channel will close Stream, but what about the reverse?

```
try (InputStream ioStream = getInputStream()) {
    ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(ioStream);
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, abuse your IDE, use control+click to navigate into JDK source and find the real code that will be run. This way you will be able to answer questions like that for yourself. Java IDE are pretty good at navigating code and modern JDK include source code for everything.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, the `InputStream` knows nothing about the `Channel`, so closing the `InputStream` **cannot** automatically close the `Channel`.

However, trying to read from the `Channel` after the `InputStream` has been closed will throw an `IOException`:

- the channel has to fetch data from the inputstream through `InputStream.getBytes()`
- `InputStream.getBytes()` will throw an `IOException` if the inputstream has been closed.

---

For the special case of a `FileInputStream` the `Channels.newChannel(ioStream)` call will return `FileInputStream.getChannel()`, so in this special case closing the inputstream will also close the channel.

Comment: And to note: In this case its the `InputStream` which holds the resources, so as long at it's closed it doesn't matter if the `Channel` is closed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the core of your concern is that you don't have a "leak" by leaving resources open.

As far as I'm aware, so long as the underlying resource gets closed you won't have a leak since that underlying object (with native methods) is what's talking to the OS and keeping the resource open.

Since the documentation says that it simply redirects to the stream (emphasized in bold by me) then closing the `InputStream` itself will close the only actual resource as `Channel.newChannel(InputStream)` is not creating a new resource.

I would, however, rather open your Channel in a try-with-resources and let it be closed automatically, which will cascade to the underlying resource.

User Slaw has the correct idea that the `InputStream` has no knowledge of the Channel (except in the special case of a `FileInputStream` as shown by Alex). This is one of the reasons you should close your wrapper resources rather than *just* the underlying resources, so that your wrappers have consistent knowledge of the actual resource.

---

> ### java.nio.channels.Channels.newChannel(InputStream) - Java 1.8 API
>
> Constructs a channel that **reads bytes from the given stream**.
>
> The resulting channel will not be buffered; **it will simply redirect its I/O operations to the given stream**. Closing the channel will in turn cause the stream to be closed.
>
> Parameters:
> in - The stream from which bytes are to be read
>
> Returns:
> A new readable byte channel

Comment: That's not the answer to the question. You answer that if you close the channel it will close the stream. The question is whether it will close the channel if you close the stream.

Comment: I read the documentation @xtratic. Closing channel closes Stream. What about the reverse? Please also read my question.

Comment: @ShivaKumar Sorry, I misread the question. I see so many people ask questions before reading documentation that, admittedly, I jumped to conclusions. In my defense, it's an odd question which more than one of us misread..

Comment: Ok, np. But I think your testcase is not valid if InputStream is not FileInputStream

Comment: @ShivaKumar You're right, the test was only for a `FileInputStream`; I've removed it as it's unhelpful. I've left the main point of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation of Channels.newChannel:

```
    public static ReadableByteChannel newChannel(InputStream in) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(in, "in");

        if (in.getClass() == FileInputStream.class) {
            return ((FileInputStream) in).getChannel();
        }

        return new ReadableByteChannelImpl(in);
    }
```

As you can see, if the input stream is a file stream we have a special case. In this special case the `close()` method of the resulting channel will just return `! checked`, where `checked` is a private boolean field of the corresponding file input stream. When you close the file input stream it sets the `closed` to true and then the channel will also think that it's closed:

```
   InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("test.file"));
   ReadableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(is);
   System.out.println(channel.isOpen());  // True
   is.close();
   System.out.println(channel.isOpen());  // False
```

However, this is an implementation detail, so you can't rely on it. Also, if the input stream is not a file input stream, then the above will not work at all.

Answer (score -1):

From Java API 7:

> The resulting channel will not be buffered; it will simply redirect its I/O operations to the given stream. **Closing the channel will in turn cause the stream to be closed**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah its the same answer as xtratic hah he beat me to it

Comment: That's not the answer to the question. You answer that if you close the channel it will close the stream. The question is whether it will close the channel if you close the stream.